# Drupal: View list inside view

Tags: view, drupal-7

I have created 2 content types; Episode which has actual episode information and Channel which has a channel description which includes a few fields specific to the channel plus an Entity Reference to Episodes.

While entering data, you can select "Add new episode" and are able to add as many episodes as you wish.  The data is all visible and correct in View Content.

I need now to create a view which looks something like this:

## Channel Name

Channel Info

### Episodes:

**Ep 1**
  Ep 1 content
 **Ep 2**
  Ep 2 content
 **etc.**

I can create a view of Channels or a view of Episodes, just don't know how to integrate the one into the other.

Having the darndest time figuring out what I am doing wrong.  perhaps it's as much about terminology as anything else as I come from a different CMS background.  TIA

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the **display suite** module and linking the entities using a custom view mode, and then rendering a rendered entity in your view.

So Install the Display Suite Module.

Setup a custom View Mode, and enable the custom view in the "Parent" content type, and select single column layout.

Add the Entity Reference Field to your columns, and select rendered entity.

Then Create a new View, referencing the "Parent" Content Type, and the views output, select rendered entity and choose the custom view mode you created.

Answer (score 0):

I was over-thinking the solution. In the Manage Display for the Channel, set Episodes to display as Rendered Entity. From that point, I was able to then modify the Manage Display for the Episode content type. This was all that was necessary.

Comment: using display suite ?